# Am I screwing Vue.js' reactivity by looping over an array in the state and creating new properties inside every element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am executing the following code in my mounted() method:

```
    mounted(){
        this.sentences = this.sentences.map((sentence, index) => {
            let words = [];
            sentence.text.split(' ').forEach((word, i) => {
                words.push({
                    text: word,
                    selected: false
                })
            });
            sentence.words = words
            sentence.grade.selected = false;

            return sentence;
        })
    }
```

Originally, this.sentences looks like this:

```
sentences: [
                {
                    text: "Go away and hide behind that door where we found you just now.",
                    grade: {
                        text: 606
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "Please don't let anyone spoil these nice fresh flowers.",
                    grade: {
                        text: 609
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "The string had eight knots in it which I had to untie.",
                    grade: {
                        text: 700
                    }
                },
]
```

So I am adding a property `words` to each object in the sentences array, and a property `selected` to each object's grade property. After swapping from hard coded words and selected properties to adding them dynamically with JavaScript, the reactivity for words stopped working. I assume I'm not setting them the right way but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Answer (score 1):

The issues is limitations when adding new properties to a reactive object.

Use `Vue.set` to add new properties.

```js
Vue.set(sentence, 'words', words)
Vue.set(sentence.grade, 'selected', false)
```

Or use a computed function.

```js
computed: {
  sentencesComputed() {
    return this.sentences.map((sentence, index) => {
            let words = [];
            sentence.text.split(' ').forEach((word, i) => {
                words.push({
                    text: word,
                    selected: false
                })
            });
            sentence.words = words
            sentence.grade.selected = false;

            return sentence;
        })
  }
}
```